How can I set up Express-Session cookies in Safari using two different Fly.io apps?
Host: fly.io
Server: Node-Express
Front-end: Vite-React
I am using Fly.io for both the front-end and the server. I am using express-sessions for user auth. Safari will not save the session cookies in production, which means the entire app is unusable.
I'm in a little over my head in trying to solve this question. One idea I had would be to proxy between the two apps via fly.io config and have the browser believe the two apps are coming from the same place. I don't know anything about proxying so I am way out of my league in understanding that. Is this a possibility? Maybe change the server name to a subdomain of the main app?
My current work-around is to simply copy the front-end build to the server and run it statically from there. This is not ideal long term. Safari is the only browser stopping me from moving forward with a separated front-end app.
I know the question about Safari cookies/sessions has been asked a million times because I've been through many of those posts. However, I still haven't found an answer that can fully solve my problem.
Other work arounds that allow me to keep the apps separated will be appreciated.
I did see one post about sending the cookie info as part of a login response and manually adding it to the browser but that defeats the purpose of HttpOnly cookies, doesn't it?
I've tried setting app.set('trust proxy', 1) But that hasn't solved anything.
It does work if I turn the prevent cross-site tracking off, but I can't expect my users to do that.

The only solution that worked for me was to create a domain and a subdomain for the API from an outside source. It isn't the solution I want, but it works.


The only solution that worked for me was to create a domain and a
subdomain for the API from an outside source. It isn't the solution I
want, but it works

Cookies rely upon the Domain Names for security and shareability.
Therefore as long as the application depends on Cookies, the domain names are inevitable.
Cookies’ Security:
Cookies are a form of ambient authority. The server sets the domain attribute specifying those hosts to which the cookie will be sent. The user agent will include the cookies in making HTTP requests when the domain attribute matches with the origin server. The user agent will skip the cookies that do not match. This brings in security for Cookies within the same site.
Cookies’ Shareability:
The same domain attribute enables sharing of cookies as well. For example, the domain attribute value z@z.com matches not only with the same value, but also with every subdomain suffixed with z@z.com. For example, y.z@z.com, x.y.z@z.com, v.x.y.z@z.com and so on. This results in sharing of cookies across the same site.
sameSite attribute complements Safety:
However, the domain attribute and its matching rule, does not dictate the request types under which the cookies are applied. It means the same matching rule will be applied in both request types - same-site and cross-site. Please look below the two different type of requests - same-site and cross-site respectively, the cookies from the domain z@z.com included in the both requests. This is unsafe. This is wherein the sameSite attribute complements safety.
request # 1 same-site
document origin: z@z.com
site : z@z.com
fetch url : y.z@z.com
target : z@z.com
request type : same-site (site is the same as target)

Status : Cookies from z@z.com will be sent to y.z@z.com

request # 2 cross-site
document origin: zz@zz.com
site: zz@zz.com
fetch url : y.z@z.com
target : z@z.com
request type : cross-site (site is different from target)

Status : Cookies from z@z.com will be sent to y.z@z.com

Using sameSite attributes, the server asserts that the sameSite cookies should only be sent in same-site requests, and it should not be sent in cross-site requests. Therefore request # 2 above now will behave safely as below request # 3. Please note request # 1 will continue behaving the same way even with sameSite attribute since it is a same-site request.
request # 3 cross-site still sameSite asserted
document origin: zz@zz.com
Samesite : Strict
site: zz@zz.com
fetch url : y.z@z.com
target : z@z.com
request type : cross-site (site is different from target)

Status : Cookies from z@z.com will NOT be sent to y.z@z.com

Note: SameSite=Lax will include cookies in cross-site, still it does so only for top level safe requests (GET).
Domain names do the same key role with sameSite attribute as it did with domain attribute. A request is identified as same-site or cross-site based on the same kind of domain matching rule discussed above. For instance, request # 3 has the site zz.com and the target z.com, since the site and target do not match, it is identified as a cross-site request.
So the conclusion is, cookies have a built-in, ready to use framework for HTTP state management. Domain names are the foundation on which this framework has been relied upon. Therefore domain names are inevitable as long as Cookies are in use.

Other work arounds that allow me to keep the apps separated will be
appreciated. I did see one post about sending the cookie info as part
of a login response and manually adding it to the browser but that
defeats the purpose of HttpOnly cookies, doesn't it?

If domain names cannot be afforded, then the alternatives may be followed. However, it may add the developmental cost since it needs to be built for HTTP state management.

I've tried setting app.set('trust proxy', 1) But that hasn't solved
anything.

This statement is required when the Express server is behind a proxy server. However, it neither adds nor alters the functionalities of a Cookie system. You can read more on this here.

It does work if I turn the prevent cross-site tracking off, but I
can't expect my users to do that.

The cross-site cookies or third-party cookies are the cookies included in a cross-site request. The potential of the risks involved in this kind of cookie is mitigated by the attribute sameSite. sameSite Lax enforcement will include cookies in cross-site requests only for top level navigation with safe HTTP methods (GET).  Other than this, exchange of cookies in all cross-site requests are deemed unsafe. Therefore the trend has been set to abandon such unsafe third-party cookies and reimplement the same with adequate safety.  Safari has already started and Chrome started warning too.
References:
HTTP State Management Mechanism
Same-site Cookies draft-west-first-party-cookies-0
